# How to get standard system colours for custom widget

Tags: gtk, gtkmm

I am writing a custom widget using gtkmm and I would like to use the standard selection colour when part of my widget is selected.  For example when you select text in a text box, the background colour goes (for me) dark blue, so I want to obtain this same dark blue colour.

I have tried this, but I only get black or white, not the actual colours in use:

```
bool MyWidget::on_draw(const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& cr) {
    Gdk::Cairo::set_source_rgba(cr,
        get_style_context()->get_color(Gtk::STATE_FLAG_SELECTED));
}
```

What is the correct way to obtain the standard colours with gtkmm, such that if the user changes their colour theme, the changes will also be reflected here?

Or is it considered best practice to define some new CSS styles which inherit from the standard system ones, so that people can override colours for just my widget if they desire, without affecting others?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to render the background of a widget is to use [`gtk_render_background()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStyleContext.html#gtk-render-background). This function will take into account widget state and style.

Your code above becomes:

```cpp
bool
MyWidget::on_draw (const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& cr)
{
  double w = get_allocated_width(), h = get_allocated_height();
  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::StyleContext> context = get_style_context();

  context->render_background(cr, 0, 0, w, h);

  return true;
}
```

This way your widget will always be updated to reflect the theme.

If you want to control the color and style of your widget you should use an additional `Gtk::StyleProvider` for your application to load a custom CSS fragment with the desired style classes.

Comment: Any suggestions about how to get the current selection colour, if it's with CSS?  My widget renders a collection of items and I'd like to use the selection colour to change the background of the item that is currently selected, but not the whole control which should remain with the default background.

Comment: You can save the state of the widget, remove the SELECTED state from its flags, render the background over the whole allocation; then put back the SELECTED state, and render the background only over the area you wish to show as selected.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work - `render_background()` is white whether I call `set_state_flags(Gtk::STATE_FLAG_SELECTED, true)` or not!

Comment: Do you have a style associated to the widget?

Comment: I don't know, I'm just going off [the gtkmm custom widget tutorial](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-custom-widgets.html.en).  If styles were needed you'd think they'd be part of the tutorial!

Comment: get_style_context() will return a Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::StyleContext>, not a Gtk::StyleContext*. I had tried to edit the answer at the time but I just noticed that the edit was rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer to this is that what I was doing in the question was correct, except there were no styles applied to the widget so the colours were just black and white.

I had to add this in the widget's constructor:

```
this->get_style_context()->add_class(GTK_STYLE_CLASS_ENTRY);
```

To get text entry styles.  Of course this made `render_background()` as suggested by ebassi render a text entry background instead, which isn't what I wanted (I just wanted a solid colour.)  So instead I changed the above line (in the constructor) to:

```
this->get_style_context()->add_class(GTK_STYLE_CLASS_DEFAULT);
```

And in my render function, temporarily set text-entry styles just to get the colour:

```
auto cxStyle = this->get_style_context();
cxStyle->context_save();
cxStyle->add_class(GTK_STYLE_CLASS_ENTRY);
Gdk::Cairo::set_source_rgba(cr, cxStyle->get_background_color(Gtk::STATE_FLAG_SELECTED));
cr->fill();
cxStyle->context_restore();
```

This way I was able to obtain the text selection colour and fill a rectangle behind the area of my custom widget that should be shown as currently selected.

I couldn't use `render_background()` here because it would have drawn the background of a text control which I don't want, I just wanted a solid filled rectangle.

Comment: You can set up the style context in any way you like, and then call render_background() with it. You can also define a style class in any way you want. I'd also like to point out that get_background_color() is deprecated because it does not make sense in CSS (an image or a gradient are not a color, and you can have them all in CSS). The whole point is: if you're using the style context API then you need to use the render_* API as well.

Comment: @ebassi: I'm just going off the [gtkmm custom widget example](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-custom-widgets.html.en) - if `get_background_color()` is deprecated then it might be a good idea to update the tutorial!  I have no idea about style classes - is there an example like this tutorial that shows best practice for using them?

Comment: You should file a bug against gtkmm — https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=gtkmm&component=documentation — gtkmm is a binding, and it's maintained separately from GTK itself. For style classes, see GtkCssProvider to load a custom CSS, GtkStyleContext::add_provider() to add the new provider, and GtkStyleContext::add_class() to add a class to the widget; then you need to write the CSS you need.